# JQuery won't pull text from text field within Rails Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Jquery and this is making me pull my hairout.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> User Data </th>
    <th> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= f.label :user_name, 'User name' %> </td>
    <td> <%= f.text_field :user_name %> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= f.label :hobby, 'Hobby' %> </td>
    <td id="takeme"> <%= f.text_area :hobby %> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a id="send-thoughts" href="">Click</a>
<script>
  jQuery("a#send-thoughts").click(function() {
    var thought = jQuery("td#takeme").val();
    alert(thought);
  });
  //  $("td#takeme").val("monkey cheese");
</script>
```

This won't pull the value from the "takeme" field when I click the link....why not??

Note: changing

```
jQuery("td#takeme").val();
```

to

```
jQuery("td#takeme").hide();
```

does, indeed, hide the field -- so it does work for at least something. But I can't pull the contents!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead, you are selecting the parent instead of the actual input

```
$("td#takeme > textarea").val();
```

**or**

assign an `id` directly to the text area

```
<%= f.text_area :hobby, id: 'hobby_text' %>
```

and then in JS

```
$("#hobby_text").val();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: When I do that, the alert just says "undefined" (without that, the alert just displays a blank entry, regardless of whether I typed anything into the text area.)

Comment: Its not `$("td#takeme > input").val();`, its `$("td#takeme > textarea").val();`

Comment: ohhhh the second method worked. thanks! the newly edited first one is probably good too

Comment: Glad that helped!